# How to align cards in Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to arrange cards in row format but they are displayed in column format. I have attached an image of the result. The first card is shown correctly, but I want to show the second card on the right side of the first card and so on. But in my code the second card is placed below the first card.

HTML view file

```html
<md-content class="md-padding layout-xs-column layout-row" layout-xs="column" layout="row" ng-repeat="product in vm.result">      
  <div layout="column" flex-xs flex-gt-xs="30" class="layout-row flex-xs flex-gt-xs-30">
    <md-card>
      <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
          <span class="md-title">{{ product.Product_Name }}</span>
        </md-card-header-text>
      </md-card-header>
      <img ng-src="{{ product.Image }}" class="md-card-image" alt="Image here">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Brand: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Brand }}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Color: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Color }}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Price: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Price }}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Url: </span><span style="margin-left:10px"><a ng-href="{{ product.Url }}">{{ product.Url }}</a></span>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Category: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Category }}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold;">Description: </span><span style="margin-left:10px">{{ product.Description }}</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="start center">
        <md-button class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="vm.editDialog($index,product._id)">Edit</md-button>
        <md-button name="ProductId" class="send-button md-accent md-raised" ng-click="remove(product._id,'{{$index}}')">Remove</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Car image:

[image: card image]

Second card is shown below the first one instead of side-by-side:

[image]

Because of that long description all other cards are not shown properly:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `ng-repeat` at wrong place. It should be used in `div` element rather than using in `md-content`. see the below code. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/GZvgrK

Comment: thank you it's working now but every product is in same one row but i want 3 product in first row and 3 second row like that.

Comment: http://codepen.io/next1/pen/NNvPwb Just you appropriate flex value to get the desired result.

Comment: yes fixed but so much of space are wasting because some products has less description and some has more that time so much space wasted. The image shoes that and that image added to above question

Comment: Just chek the above link once again. use `md-conent` with inline styling to specify it's height.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps so much to me.

Comment: No problem at all. :)